# dataframe where one column only has na values omitted

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame "accdata".

```
 dim(accdata)
[1] 6496  188
```

One of the variables - "VAL" is of interest to me. I must calculate the number of instances where VAL is equal to 24.

I tried a few functions that returned error messages. After some research it seems I need to remove the NA values from VAL first.

I would try something like `nonaaccdaa <- na.omit(accdata)` except this removes instances of NA in any variable, not just VAL.

I tried `nonaval <- na.omit(accdata[accdata$VAL])` but when I then checked the number of rows using nrow the result was null. I had expected a value between 1 and 6,496.

Whats up here?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: `(accdata$VAL[!is.na(accdata$VAL)] == 24)` should do it??

Comment: Thanks Arun, I'm sure I'll refer to this in the future too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sum(accdata$VAL == 24, na.rm=TRUE)
```